# How do I edit a Direct Connection Workspace using arcpy.da.Editor?

Tags: arcpy

How to start editor to edit version data for ArcGIS 10.1 direct connection. I tried as given below code but it is throwing an error "Operation only allowed by the owner of the version [SDE.DEFAULT]". We are able to edit features manually.

```
workspace = "Database Connections/Connection.sde"
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)
edit.startEditing(False, True)
edit.startOperation()
```

Comment: Is the SDE.DEFAULT version protected?

Comment: Yes, it is protected.

Answer (score 5):

When a Version is "protected", only the owner can change it. Since this is not the default, someone with access to the SDE user password made this change. Doing so is common to prevent uncontrolled edits of the SDE.DEFAULT state. Either your app should be editing off child versions from SDE.DEFAULT, or it should be making a new child version, then editing that, or if the SDE.DEFAULT version *really* shouldn't be PROTECTED, you'd need to change it back to PUBLIC.